# How do I select multiple items in Listbox by holding CTRL button in C#?

Tags: c#, listbox

My code right here will only select items if a user drags the mouse down. How do I make it instead so that the user can select multiple items if they use the CTRL button?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.MultiColumn = true;
        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I tried to drag the code my Form1.Designer.cs but it won't work

```
listBox1.MultiColumn = true;
listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
```

The error it's giving me is this.

```
The name 'SelectionMode' does not exist in the current context.
```

Comment: It already works that way.  Why you want to forbid selecting items by dragging is very unclear.

Comment: @HansPassant OK but how do you make it so that it can do CTRL + Click as well instead of just dragging?

Comment: *It already works that way*.  Also try Shift+Click.

Comment: @HansPassant Wow I didn't know that. Oh well now that I tested it out it should work. BTW, I tried to drag the SelectionMode and Multicolumn into the designer CS file but it won't work. Instead it's giving me an error that SelectionMode does not exist in current content.

Comment: @purtpcc: Don't drag/drop the code. Use the Properties window (click on the `ListBox`, then the Properties window in the lower-right corner), and just set the two values there instead. Let the designer do its job.

Comment: @KenWhite Which property in ListBox do I change in order to get the same code I got?

Comment: @puretppc: `MultiColumn` and `SelectionMode` (in the **Behavior** section), of course. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks it worked. Just wondering, how do I display a count of how many items are being selected in my list box after pressing a button?

Comment: @puretppc: That's a totally different question. Read the `ListBox` documentation at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) - I can't post a specific link because you didn't indicate whether it was WinForms or WPF, but you can select it in the designer and hit F1 - and if you can't figure it out by looking at the properties (tip: look at those starting with `Selected`), post a new question here to ask about it.